# Customizing The opening of a Modal Dialogue

Tags: typescript, dialog, material-ui

Im trying to use a Modal Dialogue in my React Material-UI project. Material-UI provides a button in their JSX which triggers a `handleClickOpen` method call, Which i want to bypass so i can either provide my own button(that i dont want to hard code in since it could be in different formats etc...). Ive tried using props where in the custom props i have to pass in a ReactComponentElement, But adding onClick events to things like this after its been initiated is a pain.

Is there a way to open the Dialogue from an outside source? So i can create the element then some handler class can open it? Thanks for the help in advance!

Heres the base code im using from Material-UI: https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#customized-dialogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by bypassing their method, as they are simply using that to change the state that controls whether or not the dialog is visible, and you will have to change state somewhere to trigger the appearance of the dialog, unless you render it conditionally.

If you want to open the dialog from different places, then I recommend keeping its controlled state higher up and passing that down through props to wherever you are keeping the dialog. If you do this, you can also pass down the state changing method to wherever you need it using props as well, so you can have multiple buttons that call the `handleClickOpen/Close`.

Comment: Great, It worked out just fine! I kept a state of open or closed and then provided public methods in the stateful class that could be accessed!

Comment: Glad it helped!